# How to draw the root locus diagram for negative gain in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

The function `rlocus` draws the positive gain root locus of the system. How can I draw the negative gain root locus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For negative gain values just place a  minus sign  in front of `num` or `sys`, where the syntax for the function in transfer
function and in “system” formats are:

```
rlocus(num; den);
rlocus(sys);
```